# Avoid vertical-align: middle extending height of containing block

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, centering

Given the following (also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61omkd9d/)):

```css
div {
    font-size: 28px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 36px;
}
div:first-child::before {
    content: "Hi!";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>xHello, world!</div>
<div>xHello, world!</div>
```

The second div (i.e., that without the vertically aligned middle content) is 36px high (as one would expect; the single line box within it has a height of 36px, per `line-height`).

The first div is 39px high here (with subpixel rendering, some slight variation is expected here, so 39px/40px are both reasonable expectations), as the line box of the  content `::before` it extends beyond the 36px of the "normal" content, due to its vertical alignment. How can I get the containing block (i.e., the div) to extend only to 36px high (assume I'm not concerned about the content `::before` overflowing it)?

The typical approach of taking it out of the normal flow doesn't work here as then it ceases to be vertically aligned. Given the height of a block level element is dependent upon the bottommost line box within it, is this even plausible?

Comment: Vertical alignment means nothing there, you control the height using line-height, look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61omkd9d/2/).

Comment: @skobaljic It matters nothing in the example above only because it so happens that the font-size of the `::before` content is equal to the x-height of the content of the div; if you change the font-size of `::before` to 8px it makes it far clearer that it matters.

Comment: Yes, but than it looks like a bug (and maybe it is), both elements are inline, so they should stay in-line. Best way to control the height of inline elements is line-height.

Comment: This is quite clearly what CSS 2.1 describes, I'm pretty sure. `line-height` and `vertical-align` are fairly decently tested in the test suite, so I'd be surprised if it were a bug consistent across every browser. :)

Comment: @skobaljic [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) quite clearly applies to inline elements.

Comment: Yes mate, but he said `it extends beyond the 36px of the "normal" content, due to its vertical alignment`, which is not true. Text will stay inside its `line-height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::before` element inherits the 36px line-height. As far as I understand, it does not need that line-height since you are using vertical-align method of centering text. In fact, this unnecessarily tall line height is causing the issue. Reset it:

```css
div {
  font-size: 28px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 36px;
}
div:first-child::before {
  content: "Hi!";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 8px;
  /* the line height is inherited, reset it */
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>xHello, world!</div>
<div>xHello, world!</div>
```

Comment: Again, vertical-align has no effect here.

Comment: Compare the position of `Hi!` and `x` when (i) using vertical align (ii) line-height. They are different. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/61omkd9d/4/).

Comment: It should be removed, it has negative effect - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61omkd9d/3/)

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Why should line height be removed?

Comment: vertical align, not line-height. but even line-height can be removed if you do not want 36px.